# EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception when calling a Swift closure from C

Tags: ios, c, swift, closures, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to call a Swift closure from C.

The following piece of code shall represent what I'm currently working on.

First, in Swift, I initialize a static constant, the closure that is supposed to be called later.

This closure is then passed to a C function (`api_set_callback_block`) that stores the block pointer.

Some time after that, the C function `api_trigger_block` is called. This function should invoke the Swift closure. Instead of doing so, it always throws a runtime error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to access `cb_block_cb()` (also see below).

Usually, this should mean that something tries to access a previously stored variable was deallocated. However, I don't get how that could be the case as I was passing a static constant.

I double-checked that `cb_block_cb` is not NULL when accessing it.

```c
void (^cb_block_cb)(int, int) = NULL;
void api_set_callback_block(void (^cb_block)(int, int))
{
    if (cb_block == NULL)
    {
        puts("error: when setting callback block: cb_block is null");
        return;
    }
    cb_block_cb = cb_block;
}

void api_trigger_block()
{
    if (cb_block_cb == NULL)
    {
        puts("error: when triggering callback block: cb_block_cb is null");
        return;
    }
    cb_block_cb(3,3); // <-- This is where the exception gets thrown
}
```

```swift
class CustomClass: NSObject {
    public static let callback: (Int32, Int32) -> Swift.Void = { (cid, aid) in
        print("Callback block called!")
    }
}

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        api_set_callback_block(CustomClass.callback)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 7) {
            api_trigger_block()
        }
        return true
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the interesting question.

I see a few options.

**Option 1:**

If you have control over the C API, make (some part of) it Objective-C by just changing the extension from `.c` to `.m`.  Then your Swift code should interoperate with it just fine.  At least the part of it that directly interacts with Swift code should be made Objective-C.  Objective-C portion will hopefully be interoperable with the remaining C parts (the ones in `.c` files).

**Option 2:**

Write an Objective-C wrapper (in a `.m` file) around the C API and use the wrapper in Swift code.  Sample wrapper based on your example:

```
// This is where we store the block passed in from Swift
void (^cb_block_cb2)(int, int) = NULL;

// This wrapper will be used in the block passed to C API
void block_wrapper(int i1, int i2) {
    cb_block_cb2(i1, i2);
}

// Obj-C wrapper around C API block setter
// Make this available to Swift, e.g. via bridging header.
void api_set_callback_block2(void (^cb_block)(int, int))
{
    if (cb_block == NULL)
    {
        puts("error: when setting callback block: cb_block is null");
        return;
    }
    cb_block_cb2 = cb_block;
    api_set_callback_block(^(int a, int b){ block_wrapper(a, b);});
}

// Obj-C wrapper around C API block trigger
// Make this available to Swift, e.g. via bridging header.
void api_trigger_block2()
{
    puts("Entered api_trigger_block2()");
    if (cb_block_cb2 == NULL)
    {
        puts("error: when triggering callback block: cb_block_cb2 is null");
        return;
    }
    api_trigger_block();
    puts("Returned from callback in api_trigger_block2()!!!!");
}
```

Conceptually, the above options are similar.  You may be able to come up with some other options along the same lines.  At this point I can't give a good technical explanation as to why the above works.  As far as I can tell from experimenting, Swift functions/closures can't always be passed to C functions compiled with a C compiler and taking compatible blocks.  However, it works fine if the same functions are compiled as Objective-C.  A block defined in an Objective-C file can be passed to C code just fine.

For the record, I also tried using `@objc` and `@convention(c)` annotations in Swift code trying to fix this, but to no avail.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `At this point I can't give a good technical explanation as to why the above works.` I'm even more curious about why Swift closures cannot always be passed to C functions, specifically regarding my example above. At the time, we just changed the C block to a C function pointer, which literally works the same and, luckily, worked fine. Anyways, I still think your solution is quite helpful to people who don't have direct access to the underlaying C code. Btw, do you think I could/should try filing a bug report?

Comment: Indeed, it is really strange that changing blocks to function pointers makes the code work, which I double-checked.  Another interesting observation is that the code seems to be looping for awhile before crashing (try inserting a `puts()` at the beginning of `api_trigger_block()`).  As for submitting a bug report, I would suggest asking another, even shorter, question that shows function pointers working, while blocks don't.  If no one comes up with a good explanation, I'd file a bug report.